# Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError even though I am just defining a variable?

Tags: python

```
def alphabet_war(airstrikes):
    bombs = []
    for i in range(len(airstrikes)):
        bombs.append([])

    for bomb in airstrikes:
        bomb_index = index(bomb)
        for index in range(len(bomb)):
            if bomb[index] == "*":
                bombs[bomb_index].append(index)

    return bombs
```

I am getting a `"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'index' referenced before assignment"` for line `bomb_index = index(bomb)`.

While I have seen many articles on this, including: https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment/
that is quite helpful.

I am still struggling to understand why I am getting this error. I don't see how I am using it before assigning it locally? I thought all I am doing is defining `bomb_index`

I have also tried changing it slightly to the more concise:

```
for bomb in airstrikes:
    for index in range(len(bomb)):
        if bomb[index] == "*":
            bombs[index(bomb)].append(index)
```

But here for `index(bomb)` I get a `int object not callable error`

Comment: ```index(bomb)```, are you trying to get the index position? Of course, ```index``` is referenced before the ```for``` loop, hence the error

Comment: first use of index is here `bomb_index = index(bomb)` and before this index is never defined, so this is why

Comment: Yes! - without doing 'for bomb in range(len(airstrikes))- because if I do this then the remaining code won't make sense.

Comment: You get index of an element in a list by using the format list.index(element). You have to use it on a list.

Comment: So how do I define it? I can't do index(bomb) = 0 right?

Comment: @Nastor but I want to get the same index as 'bomb' while I am looping over airstrikes so how can I do this?

Comment: `airstrikes.index(bomb)`. You're getting the index of the first element 'bomb' inside list 'airstrikes' with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `bomb_index = index(bomb)`, `index` is not a defined name at that point of your code.

Presumably, what you want is to know what index `bomb` has in `airstrikes`.
The **wrong** way to do this (still using `list.index()` as you originally intended) is:

```
bomb_index = airstrikes.index(bomb) # scans airstrikes at every iteration searching for bomb
```

The **right** way to do this is to enumerate the items in the list as you loop over them:

```
for bomb_index, bomb in enumerate(airstrikes): # no need for searching, you loop and know the index of every item as you loop over them
    for index in range(len(bomb)):
        if bomb[index] == "*":
            bombs[bomb_index].append(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

`bomb_index = index(bomb)`

`index` is undefined, because its firstly declared by the for loop directly below it. I think what you're trying to do here is loop trough list values and indices simultaneously. For this, you can use `enumerate`:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for index, value in enumerate(lst):
    print(index, value)
    
#  Returns:
#  0 a
#  1 b
#  2 c
```